# Countable graph that is "as non-traceable as it gets"

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hamiltonian-paths

If $\omega$ denotes the set of the natural numbers (= the first infinite ordinal), and if $E\subseteq\binom{\omega}{2}$ is any subset, we call a map $f\colon\omega\to\omega$ a *walk* in the graph $(\omega,E)$ if and only if $\{f(k),f(k+1)\}\in E$ for all $k\in\omega$.

We call $f$ a walk a *Hamiltonian walk*<sup>1</sup> if and only if it is surjective.

**Question.**

Is there $E \subseteq \binom{\omega}{2}$ such that

1. there *is* at least one Hamiltonian walk in $(\omega,E)$,
2. *every* Hamiltonian walk in $(\omega,E)$ visits every vertex infinitely-often?

**Remarks.**

- <sub>A walk need not be injective, nor need it be surjective.</sub>
- <sub>Condition 1. implies that $(\omega,E)$ is a connected graph.</sub>
- <sub>In graph theory, an injective walk is called a *path*. (This is accidentally different from the usual convention in topology, where the term 'path' signals that self-intersections *are* permitted.)</sub>
- <sub>In graph theory, a graph admitting an injective and surjective walk into it is called *traceable*. (For finite graphs, the term *Hamiltonian* most often means that there exists a Hamilton path whose end-vertices are *adjacent*, i.e., a Hamilton circuit. For infinite graphs, this does not make sense (simply because then a Hamilton path does not have two "end-vertices"), which necessitates either (0) keeping to the study of Hamilton-paths only, or (1) using definitions involving some kind of 'convergence'.) This explains the focus of this question on Hamilton-paths, and the title of the OP.</sub>

<sup>1</sup><sub>This terminology harmonizes rather well with e.g. the book [Futaba Fujie, Ping Zhang: *Covering Walks in Graphs*. SpringerBriefs in Mathematics,
2014](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-0305-4).</sub>

Comment: Re "     the proper term for a not necessarily injective "path"     ": the usual convention is that this is just 'path'. For the record: 'path'='continuous map $[0,1]\to$(the space)', while 'arc'='map $[0,1]\to$(the space) which is a homeomorphism onto its image'. The latter condition is equivalent to 'injective' **if** (the space) is a Hausdorff space.) Note that this convention jarrs with the usual graph-theoretic convention which has 'path'='walk without **any** repetitions whatsoever'. This is just historical hazard.

Comment: Wouldn't a two-sided infinite path do?

Comment: @Dominic van der Zypen: extensive edits were made to your OP. I think that all these edits are right. In particular, the connectedness-condition was superfluous and misleading, unless I am missing something obvious. The term 'Hamiltonian walk' is an attested technical term. And Wojowu answered your question, and should perhaps make it an official answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge: it cannot, something was mixed up. Thanks for pointing out. I am too accustomed to working with Hamilton **circles** in infinite graphs. Will delete the comment. For the time being, what counts is that Wojowu answered the OP.

Comment: And for the record: the connectedness-condition in the original version of the OP was superfluous since (there is a Hamiltonian walk)$\Rightarrow$ (the graph is connected).

Comment: And to make this exchange understandable to inexperienced readers: I erroneously claimed that a Freudenthal-compactified double-ray $R=(V,E,\{\omega_{-\infty},\omega_\infty\})$ would admit a Hamiltonian walk  $f\colon\omega\to V$ in the OP's sense whose topological closure would equal $V\cup\{\omega_{-\infty},\omega_\infty\}$. I even claimed there to be infinitely-many such maps visiting any vertex more ofthen than any constant lower bound. This is **false**, as Nate Eldredge pointed out. The topological closure of the image of such a map can contain at most one end. (And may contain none.)

Comment: What about an infinite tree with all vertex degrees equal to 3? This works even for a path infinite in both directions.

Comment: What about $G=K_2$?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: what you say is true. The question in the OP is rather unproblematic. It could be 'corrected', though, by using the language of [ends in graphs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X10001962). Note that the Freudenthal-compactification of the "infinite tree with all vertex degrees equal to 3" that you mention *does not have any Hamilton-like spanning substructure, whether 'Hamilton-circle', 'one-way-infinite Hamilton path', or 'two-way-infinite Hamilton-path'; none of them can converge to more than two ends, and the tree you mention has $2^{\aleph_0}$ ends*.

Comment: @JanKyncl: mea culpa. This Achilles' heel was unintentionally introduced by *me* when simplifying-away the connectedness-condition in the original version of the OP. I still think that that condition was confusing, but the initial version excluded your (now correct) example. This should not happen. I was not respecting the OP enough. I will edit accordingly, but will also *not* exclude Wojowu's correct example, which also applies to the original OP. I will make it equivalent to the original OP.

Comment: @Dominic van der Zypen: extensive edits were made to your question again. I am sorry that I accidentally introduced 'an Achilles' heel' by a well-meant edit. I think that now the question is again equivalent in mathematically to the original version, and improved. Note, however, that the question was and is *easy* to answer, and Wojowu did. If Wojowu does not make it an official answer soon, it seems best that you write a brief answer yourself, acknowledging Wojowu. While it also seems not legal to substantially change a question, there could be a less trivial follow-up question, using 'ends'.

Comment: @PeterHeinig - that's OK, I appreciate constructive edits (which they all were!). Thanks and best wishes!

Comment: @PeterHeinig: So perhaps in conditions 1. and 2., $V$ should be replaced by $\omega$, right?

Comment: @JanKyncl: yes. Many thanks. Was an oversight. Will correct.